# Issues playing local files with AVPlayer?

Tags: objective-c, video, avfoundation, avplayer, nsurl

Basically, I'm writing a video file to the `Application Support` directory and then saving it's path:

```
NSString *guid = [[NSUUID new] UUIDString];
NSString *outputFile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"video_%@.mp4", guid];
NSString *outputDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *tempPath = [outputDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:outputFile];
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:tempPath]
// code to write a video to fileURL
```

I save the string path itself by calling `[fileURL path];`

Now later when I try to create an `AVAssetItem` from it, I can't actually get it to play.

EDIT:

Ok, so it seems the issue is the space in `Application Support`. I tried saving the file to just the `Library` directory and it worked fine.

So the question becomes, how can I play a video I save in the `Application Support` directory. I wasn't able to create a valid `NSURL` without escaping the space (when I tried it would return a nil `NSURL`) but it seems that the space/escaping doesn't allow it to play correctly.

Assume the NSURL to NSString conversion is required (unless it **really** should be avoided).

Also, side note, but if anyone could give some insight as to why this question was down voted so I can improve the quality of my questions, that would be appreciated. I don't understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I am not informed enough to opine about whether this would change if I had used matt's recommended methods: `URLForDirectory:inDomain:appropriateForURL:create:error:` and  `URLByAppendingPathComponent:` the actual issue here isn't converting an `NSURL` to `NSString`

It's that I'm saving the full URL (`[fileURL path]`). This is because the `[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];` dynamically changes and the full path won't always point me to the appropriate file.

Instead I need to save just the name of my file (in my case I needed to persist `outputFile`) and then later dynamically build the the full path when I need it.

The same exact process:

```
NSString *outputDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *tempPath = [outputDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:outputFile];
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:tempPath];
```

worked just fine.

**TLDR: Saving a full path doesn't work**